# Address page pagination opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I am facing issue in pagination of address page in Opencart. Only one address is listed even if there are couple of address added by the customer.

I have checked both the address.php file in controller and model folder. I tried to debug by putting flags and producing the no intermediate result.

1) In >model>accounts>address.php

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "address WHERE customer_id = '" . (int)$this->customer->getId() . "'"); $num_rows_1 = $query->num_rows; $num_row_1 is echoing 3
```

while

2) In >controller>account>address.php

```
$results = $this->model_account_address->getAddresses(); $noofresult=count($results);
```

$noofresult is echoing 1

Some data is getting lost. I tried to debug more but couldn't figure out. I checked this code from Opencart website code repository and everything looks good.

Can any one help me in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that you have an incoherence between what it is obtained on your address.php model and what you get on your controller returned from that function. Please, give me more information in order to help you.